# Multiple variables definition in a bash sourced file behave differently

Tags: bash

I have a .env file with the following:

```sh
FST_TEST=1
SCD_TEST=2
```

I run `source .env` and then:

- If I run `echo "$FST_TEST$FST_TEST"` it prints `1`.
- If I run `echo "$SCD_TEST$SCD_TEST"` it prints `22`.

I would have expected `echo "$FST_TEST$FST_TEST"` to also prints `11` but I can't manage to do it... I think there is something with the `Return` character.

Comment: It shows `11` for me. Any typo at your end, may be? `echo "$FST_TEST$FST_TEST"
11`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I run `source .env` before running `echo "$FST_TEST$FST_TEST"`. I've edited my question.
I checked once again with the example I provided, I don't think I have any typo and it still shows `1`.

Comment: @Romain : Can't be, unless `FST_TEST` is `1`. Do a `echo $FST_TEST` before.

Comment: @user1934428, yes `FST_TEST` is `1`: running `echo $FST_TEST` prints `1`.

Comment: So you are saying that the line  `FST_TEST=1; echo $FST_TEST$FST_TEST` (please copy and paste it) outputs `22` on your system?????

Comment: @user1934428, no, running `FST_TEST=1; echo $FST_TEST$FST_TEST` outputs `11`.

Comment: See - this is the expected behaviour. So we see that in your earlier tests, FST_TEST did not contain a `1`. If you can reproduce this case, inspect the content of `FST_TEST` on a hexadecimal level, not with `echo`, for instance by doing a `export FST_TEST; printenv FST_TEST|xxd` instead of `echo $FST_TEST`, to show its value.

Comment: Never used the printenv command before so I may use it incorrectly: I run `source .env` then `export FST_TEST; printenv FST_TEST|xxd` and it outputs `00000000: 310d 0a                                  1..`. If I run `source .env` and then `export SCD_TEST; printenv SCD_TEST|xxd` it outputs `00000000: 320a                                     2.`. Philippe on the answer found out that it was due to the Windows/DOS format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, it's because .env file is in Windows/DOS format.
Can you do :

```
dos2unix .env
```

With DOS end of line, FST_TEST=1, is actually FST_TEST=1\r.
\r makes the cursor go to beginning of the line, so the 1
you saw is two 1s, one on top the other.
On the second line, you didn't put end of line, so there was no problem.

Comment: This was the solution, thanks ! Now running `dos2unix .env` then `source .env` then `echo "$FST_TEST$FST_TEST"` correctly outputs `11`. I wouldn't have expected any different behavior from the linux subsystem... Would you mind explaining a bit ?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what does your .env file contains. Can you send its content??

Maybe try this:
    echo ${FST_TEST}${FST_TEST}

Hope it helps.

Comment: The `.env` file contains the 2 variables declarations. Its content is exactly what I copy/pasted in the first block code of my question.
Running `echo ${FST_TEST}${FST_TEST}` prints `1`.

Comment: For me it prints 11. Are you using bash?

Comment: I think so, in fact I am using the linux subsystem for windows.  If I run `echo "${BASH_VERSION}"` I have `4.4.20(1)-release` as output.

Comment: I have the same version. This is strange.

Comment: @Philippe found the solution in another answer above. Apparently this is due to the Windows/DOS format of the .env file... I have no more info on this. But anyway thanks very much for your help!